# Are there any Canadian credit cards that offer medical insurance for 30 days for the secondary user?

Tags: canada, insurance, payment-cards

I've been looking around for a Canadian credit card that offers out-of-country medical insurance for at least 30 days. I notice a lot of cards have 7 days or less. Does such a card exist? A card will realistic policies not one with 30 day coverage with so much red tape that you will never have  a successful claim.

Edit: After more research it appears only primary card holders are covered? What I'm wondering is whether there exists a card that covers secondary/additonal users too.

Comment: Suggest splitting second part into another question...

Comment: @Mark Mayo : Yep, probably should...

Answer (score 3):

According to [creditcards.ca](http://www.creditcards.ca/credit-card-news/travel-credit-cards-with-free-health-insurance-1273.php),

> ScotiaGold Passport represents the most generous coverage since its
>   no-charge emergency travel insurance lasts for up to 31 days per trip.

and:

> BMO World Elite's coverage is capped at 21 days per period of travel,
>   while Aspire World covers 22-day journeys for Canadians under the age
>   of 65

I also found a table comparing cards on [rewardscanada](http://blog.rewardscanada.ca/2013/02/travel-reward-credit-card-medical.html):

showing that National Bank of Canada actually has one that gives up to 60 days, among other cards offering 31 days as well.

[TheStar](http://www.thestar.com/business/personal_finance/2014/01/05/read_the_fine_print_if_youre_travelling_with_creditcard_insurance.html) also compares a few with some warnings, but once again mentions National Bank of Canada and their 60 day policy.

Comment: For people in their fifties or older, the age restrictions can bite as well- reducing the coverage period significantly in some cases.